# Which version is my MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql

What's the query syntax to determine the exact version number of the MySQL server software?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`SHOW VARIABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html):

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'version';`

Answer (score 3):

select version();

Answer (score 2):

Command line:

```
mysql --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned solutions you can simply see the version if you type `mysql` in your shell. You will get something like this:

```
[nikola@localhost]# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 386102
Server version: 5.1.61 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Where you can see that the version is printed in the line `Server version: 5.1.61 Source distribution`.