# How can I learn MySql version?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which version is my MySQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336712/which-version-is-my-mysql-server)

As question indicates how can I learn my 'mysql' server's version by using terminal?

Answer (score 7):

If you have the mysql client installed you can use that to connect to your database server and issue the following statement:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

For example you could use this:

```
echo SELECT VERSION() | mysql -u foo ...other parameters here...
```

The result will look something like this:

```
VERSION()
5.1.41-community
```

Answer (score 2):

The STATUS command displays the version as well as version comment information. For example:

mysql> STATUS;

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the terminal, you can check using:

```
mysql -V
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal and type in `mysql`. You should see something like this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 205
Server version: 5.1.53 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

`mysql -V` works too and outputs something like this:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.53, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do that. You can do:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
```

or

```
mysql> SELECT @@version;
```

or

```
mysql> STATUS;
```